# Link detected: no - for bond0 on RHEL 6.4

Tags: linux

[linux-networking](/questions/tagged/linux-networking)
Problem: No link detected for eth2
(Engineer says, all lights showing green for eth2 on the switch.)

Current setup:

- bond0 using eth0 and eth2 <-- bond0 working no issues
- bond0 is up with eth0, but for eth2 says no link detected. <--- failover setup, but eth2 link/cable not detected by OS

I understand there is no cable connected for eth2. But my engineer says, all lights show green on the switch for eth2.

Can anybody help out, how to check this problem?

Comment: Ask the engineer to trace the cables and double-check connectivity.

Comment: please edit with results of

# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

# ethtool eth0
# ethtool eth2

Comment: Did you change your NIC card recently or modified any settings recently?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring the interface up with:

```
ifconfig eth2 up
```

or

```
ifup eth2
```

I have had cases when the interface showed green but it wasn't up yet on the machine for some reason.

Comment: Since I can't add a comment to the original question I am commenting mine. Check if the MAC addres for `eth2` in file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` is the same as the one in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2.`